# No parameter form of a constructor

Tags: java

I am trying to create a no parameter form of a constructor for the constructor I have created below. I have provided my attempts at trying to write this constructor. Is this correct?

```
/**
 * Default Constructor for Testing
 */
public void extractTokens(Scanner scanner ) 
     throws IOException, FileNotFoundException 
{
  //extracts tokens from the text file
  File text = new File("E:/LEWIS BC 2/java project/project 1 part 3/items_all.txt");

  String toolName = scanner.next();
  String itemCode = scanner.next();
  String power = scanner.next();
  String timesBorrowed = scanner.next();
  String onLoan = scanner.next();
  String cost = scanner.next();
  String weight = scanner.next();

  extractTokens(scanner);

  // System.out.println(parts.get(1)); // "en"
}


/**
 * Creates a collection of tools to be stored in a tool list
 */
public Shop(  String toolName, 
              int power,
              int timesborrowed,
              boolean rechargeable,
              int itemCode,
              int cost,
              double weight,
              int toolcount,
              boolean onLoan  )
{
  toolsList = new ArrayList<Tool>();
  toolName = new String();
  power = 0;
  timesborrowed = 0;
  rechargeable = true;
  itemCode = 001;
  cost = 100;
  weight = 0.0;
  toolCount = 0;
  onLoan = true;
}

/**
 * Default Constructor for Testing
 */
public Shop() {
  // initialise instance variables
  toolName = "Spanner";
  itemCode = 001;
  timesBorrowed = 0;
  power = 0;
  onLoan = true;
  rechargeable = true;
  itemCode = 001;
  cost = 100;
  weight = 0.0;
  toolCount = 0;
}
```

Comment: Show the instance variables declaration.

Comment: You need to use the `this` keyword when assigning values. For example `this.toolName = "Spanner"`

Comment: I suggest working your way through a basic tutorial on this stuff.  There are many concepts that you have failed to understand.

Comment: @JustinC - That's not needed in the no-parameter constructor; but it _is_ needed in the other one.

Comment: @DavidWallace - Yes, I agree with your first comment as well. A basic tutorial would be the best solution here

Comment: @DavidWallace it isn't needed in either case. it is just good practice and prevents from silly same-name parameter scope mistakes. OP doesn't seem to understand where fields belong in java :)

Comment: If this is for an actual application and not, say, a homework assignment, I would suggested using a database to store values like those and then use something like [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) to actually deal with the data.

Answer (score 2):

You have made a lot of mistakes. First of all, fields need to exist in the class-level scope.

```
public void extractTokens(Scanner scanner ) 
     throws IOException, FileNotFoundException 
{
  //extracts tokens from the text file
  File text = new File("E:/LEWIS BC 2/java project/project 1 part 3/items_all.txt");

  String toolName = scanner.next();
  String itemCode = scanner.next();
  String power = scanner.next();
  String timesBorrowed = scanner.next();
  String onLoan = scanner.next();
  String cost = scanner.next();
  String weight = scanner.next();

  extractTokens(scanner);

  // System.out.println(parts.get(1)); // "en"
}
```

This method basically does nothing, you are declaring a lot of method-scope variables, which fall out of scope and are thus consumed by the next round of garbage collection. You have other methods that make this exact same mistake. If you need to do work on fields, you need to REFER to those fields. By saying `String toolname = scanner.next()` you are declaring a variable that holds a reference to an object of type `String`, in the METHOD scope, equalling the value of `scanner.next()`. What you want to do is declare variables on the CLASS scope, and then do work on them by referring to them. I highly suggest you qualify your references with the `this` keyword, which allows you to refer to your current instance of your object.

As far as whether your no-parameter `public` constructor was written correctly, the answer is **yes**, because you have declared a member of a class with no return type, with the same name as the class, with no parameters and with `public` visibility. There's a caveat here because your code has a 100% chance of not actually doing what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Once you introduce a second constructor, then you have two paths your code can take to initialize an object. If you're not careful you can introduce inconsistencies so that you have different values set depending on how the object got created.

In the case of your posted code introducing a second constructor seems unnecessary and will only create problems for you. Code that creates an object for a test would be better off as part of the test so it can be kept separate from your main code.

In the case where you do need alternative ways to initialize an object, there is a common pattern called constructor-chaining which aims to eliminate opportunities for inconsistent initialization. With this approach there is a single primary constructor, and one or more auxiliary constructors that build on the primary one.

```
// primary constructor
public Foo(String p1, String p2, String p3) {
  this.p1 = p1;
  this.p2 = p2;
  this.p3 = p3;
}

// auxiliary constructor
public Foo() {
  this("firstDefault", "secondDefault", "thirdDefault");
}
```

The primary constructor always gets called, other constructors call `this()` with various parameters.

Comment: Why?  Can you provide some justification?

Comment: Wouldn't be *better* just a lot cleaner.

Comment: @Shahar I disagree.  The problem with this approach is that if it doesn't work for some reason, there are two places to check - (1) did you put the right values in the brackets in the no-arg constructor, and (2) did you assign everything correctly in the "big" constructor.  "Cleaner" would be the simple approach of just doing your assignments directly in the no-arg constructor.  Readability is far more important than being clever.

Comment: @Shahar No, if it can be done it is better, since it makes the first constructor the only place that actually has to deal with the values.

Comment: @MirroredFate - not really.  Suppose there were more than three parameters.   Do you really want to work your way through a long list of values in parentheses, trying to keep track of which one is which?  Trust me, in the course of my career, I've done this both ways.  The simple approach (assignments within the no-arg constructor) is much, much more maintainable and less error-prone.  I cannot agree with this answer at all.

Comment: @DavidWallace If there are more than three parameters, or even if there are only three, you can use comments to track which is which. If you can avoid duplication of code, you should. It saves headaches down the road.

Comment: I understand what you're saying.  My experience differs from yours.  I have had far more headaches using the "this" form, than the "assignment" form.  The latter is far more maintainable.

Comment: @David: i do need to clarify this. like MirroredFate said this way there is 1 flow and 1 place for assignments. this way is mandatory in Scala, i'll try to look up their justification for this.

Comment: Yes, your answer would be much better if you provided a reason for preferring this way over the other way.  It's also a shame that @drkunibar, who has posted essentially the same answer, has also failed to give a justification for it.  I suppose I really ought to post my own answer, outlining the other way, and spelling out all the reasons for preferring it.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```
/**
* Creates a collection of tools to be stored in a tool list
*/
public Shop(String toolName, int power,int timesborrowed,boolean rechargeable,
        int itemCode,int cost,double weight,int toolcount,boolean onLoan) {
    this.toolsList = new ArrayList<Tool>();
    this.toolName = toolName;
    this.power = power;
    this.timesborrowed = timesborrowed;
    //    ... and so on ..
}

/**
 * Default Constructor for Testing
 */
public Shop(){
    // Call the previous defined constructor
    this("Spanner", 0, 0, ... and so on ...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct assuming all the variables are declared right. You can have a constructor like this:

```
public Shop() {}
```

Take for instance a dice class:

```
private num_sides;
public Dice(int sides) { this.num_sides = sides; }
public Dice() { this.num_sides = 6; } //default
```

Perfectly fine.

Comment: It is idiomatic to capitalize constants and use `this.varName` for member variables. Probably should follow that form here.

Comment: @NathanielFord `NUM_SIDES` would kind of be a constant after the object is instantiated and I didn't initially include the `this.` because it will confuse him.

Comment: @Shahar that is better indicated with the `final` keyword than by violating the normal naming conventions.